# What else does Qt5Network require when deployed?

Tags: qt, dependencies

I have successfully deployed my Qt application, with all the necessary dll files, and it works fine. However, as soon as I add something which uses Qt5Network, my program crashes with "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)".

I of course copied the Qt5Network.dll to my deployment dir, and I used a dependency walker, and found out that there was one new dependency compared to what I had before adding the "network" part: libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

I copied that as well, still the same error.

I learned that Qt Network requires OpenSSL, so I found libeay32 and ssleay32, and copied them to my deployment directory as well.

The error is the same. If I remove the requirement for Qt5Network, my program runs fine, and it uses many other modules, like Printsupport, Serialport, etc. without problem.

I tried it on Qt 5.9 and 5.15.

Comment: I believe both 5.9 and 5.15 require OpenSSL version >= 1.1.1. If I'm not mistaken, the libeay and ssleay are from older versions. The binaries you need to look for are libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll.

Comment: Just use windeployqt.exe, it will copy all required dlls with proper version (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: @jdfa : I did exactly that. And it has always worked before, just not now. Now I did it again, and all that happened was that Qt5Network.dll  was copied as well. Nothing more.

Comment: @linuxfever : I tried out the libraries you suggested, and it works. You can turn that into an answer if you want and I'll accept it. I still wonder why windeployqt is not smart enough to do that, and that it's not stated anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Qt binaries (Qt Network in your case) will try to load OpenSLL when first needed, at runtime, not when you first launch your application, see the SSL section [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html). And I believe that's the reason why dependency walker and windeployt were not able to identify OpenSSL as they can only identify load-time dependendencies.

It seems you were trying to bundle the OpenSSL binaries from an incompatible version. Starting with Qt 5.12.4 the supported OpenSSL version is 1.1.1, see for instance [here](https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/06/17/qt-5-12-4-released-support-openssl-1-1-1). If you find the binaries from v1.1.1 and bundle those, your application should work.

Comment: This was indeed the case, the libcrypto and libssl found under Tools\QtCreator\bin solved the problem.